# Displaying gui menus for Gvim plugin bash-support

Tags: bash, shell, vim, plugins

I've installed the Vim plugin bash-support. It all looks good when running the commands from vim command line (e.g  typing `\sie` adds an if else statement)
However I can't get to display the gui menus in Gvim. 
From the [docs](https://wolfgangmehner.github.io/vim-plugins/doc/bashsupport.html) I get the following: 'If the menus are not visible call them with the entry "Load Bash Support" in the standard Tools-menu.'

I believe that menu might be the Gvim gui menu, displayed by doing "set guioptions+=T". However I cant see the "Load Bash Suport" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Load Bash Support menu item should be under Tools in the menubar that contains "File, Edit, Tools..."

If that bar is missing, you may try bringing it back using `:set guioptions+=m`. Otherwise, if the menu item is still missing, you can try calling the Load Bash Support function directly by using `:call BASH_CreateGuiMenus()`.

Comment: The issue was entering gvim from my terminal instead of running it from the gvim shotcut in my ubuntu desktop. For some reason even when guioptions have +=m running it from the terminal it only displays a toolbar with icons for basic operations, save, save all, print, undo, redo...but it doesn't show the toolbar with the menus, (File, Edit, Toolbar..), which is displayed if I run it from he desktop